# parseInt not converting multiple string to int

Tags: angularjs

it was a very simple but don't no why i can't solve it.

I am trying to convert string to integer from json, it converts 1st object but from second object it doesn't:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="myApp">
  <ul ng-repeat="vals in json_arr" ng-init="parseId(vals)">
    <li>
      <input type="number" ng-model="vals.id" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="number" ng-model="vals.id1" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="number" ng-model="vals.id2" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('myApp', function($scope) {
  $scope.json_arr = [{
    'id': '1',
    'id1': '2',
    'id2': '3'
  }];

  $scope.parseId = function(val) {
    val.id = parseInt(val.id);
  }
});
```

[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/DtSGcQfAyi85YjgOdmaK?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Aahhhhh that's my mistake, In `parseId` function i only parse `val.id`.

The correct 1 is:

```
$scope.parseId = function(val) {
  val.id = parseInt(val.id);
  val.id1 = parseInt(val.id1);
  val.id2 = parseInt(val.id2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code with this one

```
$scope.parseId = function(val) {
    val.id = parseInt(val.id);
    val.id1 = parseInt(val.id1);
    val.id2 = parseInt(val.id2);
}
```

or you can change your json_arr variable than you don't need to change string to int

```
$scope.json_arr = [{
    'id': 1,
    'id1': 2,
    'id2': 3
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Directives are executed in order from highest priority to lowest priority when defined on the same element. ng-repeat has a directive priority level of [1000](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), but ng-init has a directive priority of [450](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). ng-repeat also has a terminal property - meaning it is the last directive to execute, and no other directives can execute after it.  There-in lies the problem.  The ng-repeat executes first, and because it is terminal, it will not allow ng-init to execute after.

To solve this, move the ng-init to the first li below:

```
<body ng-controller="myApp">
  <ul ng-repeat="vals in json_arr">
    <li  ng-init="parseId(vals)">
      <input type="number" ng-model="vals.id" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="number" ng-model="vals.id1" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="number" ng-model="vals.id2" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

This works because ng-model has a priority of 0, so it will execute after ng-init.

**[EDIT]**

I realized there is a logic error in the code you posted. The other two answers have already addressed it, but I'll post it again here for completeness:

```
$scope.parseId = function(val) {
    val.id = parseInt(val.id);
    val.id1 = parseInt(val.id1);
    val.id2 = parseInt(val.id2);
}
```